# JS Flexbox style CSS class aded to html file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexbox

I'm working on a search engine. And I'm having display issues, some features, style like fonts are added to my page. When I look at the elements tab I see things that do not exist in my style tag on my file. 
I have another version of this file that works perfectly without any display issues. the only difference between the two files is that each file loads data from a different database. Also the page that i'm having trouble with does not display things like the description that you can see in the second page. Here are screen shots of both:

[This is the page with the problems](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbBif.png)

[and this is the page that works fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SxDI.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. You need to explain in detail what your problem is, what you have tried, and you need to add your code here, at least a minimal runeable example. Otherway we cant help you.

Answer (score -1):

You have Modernizr in your website, which adds the classes to the HTML tag. This should however not affect your styles (if you are not specifically targeting it). If your layout actuallay does differ, you probably have different style declarations which are affected by those classes.

Modernizr is a feature detection JavaScript library. It allows to distinct between browsers, which support a feature and such that do not.

See https://modernizr.com/docs

Comment: How do I get rid of it then ?